# How a process is created?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, process

When I execute a program in unix/Linux, what really happens under the hood?

Who is responsible for creating a process?

Do I need to make a call to kernel to start a process (instance of my program) ? In that sense, my program should be running on a processor to make kernel calls right? Then how does the first kernel call happened to start of a process? Is it like a deadlock? Where exactly kernel first show-in then?

Sorry, I just read many documents about all these, but still couldn't connect the dots or get a full picture. Can someone elaborate on simple terms?

Comment: https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/What-really-happens-under-the-hood-when-we-type-ls-on-Linux https://medium.com/@mitali.s.auger/linux-under-the-hood-what-happens-when-you-type-ls-l-b8432e533794 https://medium.com/@alyragab70/linux-under-the-hood-processing-1b474f5d13f https://www.alexbod.com/what-is-linux-system-call-under-the-hood/ https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/96864/GRADU-1428493916.pdf https://kukuruku.co/post/multitasking-in-the-linux-kernel-interrupts-and-tasklets/

Comment: There seems to be more than one question here: How does a process start another process? and How is the first process created?

Answer (score 0):

Deadlock is a completely different thing.

## To create a process

Traditionally Unix had one way to create a process `fork`.
`fork` is a system call. It is called by an existing process. It is a call into the kernel. It causes a new process to be created. The new process is almost identical to the old, both processes return from the `fork` call.

The main differences between the processes are: the return value of `fork`. The process id.

You may also wish to use `exec` (also a system/kernel call) to make the process different: to run a different program.

## So how does it get started.

Process 1 is linked to the kernel. Both are loaded at the same time. The kernel starts running this process. Everything else comes from there: processes create new processes, that create new processes (see above) like the branches of a tree.

Comment: 1) The system call is `execve`.  Other variants are in the standard library.  2) In linux, there is also apparently a standard process 2, that is the parent of the kernel processes.

Comment: @DavidG I was going for not too much detail. Detail can be added latter.

Comment: @DavidG What is a standard process 2?

Comment: In Linux, for quite a few years now, process 2 is `[kthreadd]`.  It is the parent of all the kernel threads.  For instance, many devices have a thread to manage them, as do many filesstems.

Comment: @DavidG Oh that. Again going for simplicity, it does not matter.